# How long could Jack Sparrow and Will Turner survive underwater with a row boat over their heads (Pirates of the Caribbean I)?

Tags: respiration, breathing

How long could Jack Sparrow and Will Turner survive underwater with a row boat over their heads (Pirates of the Caribbean I)?

This scene would be physically infeasible due to buoyancy issues (http://kwc.org/mythbusters/2007/11/episode_92_pirates_2_row_boat.html). One may try to solve this by loading the boat itself with some heavy weights.
[image]
Here, the question is about the physiological feasibility - how long they can last with the air in that row boat. The question occurred to me because I have seen people in forumns claiming 2 people could not have made that journey with the air present in that space. But I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: +1 2 people downvoted your post without any reason and your question is fine and I think it is very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

This is my attempted solution that I would like to share and verify.

1. Volume of air.

   Assume dimensions of the boat (modeled a cuboid) = 4m x 1m x 0.5m
   Thus Volume of air, V = 2 m<sup>3</sup>.
2. Acceptable limits of air composition

   Carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) poisoning will happen far before there is any risk of running out of oxygen (O<sub>2</sub>).
   Referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide#Toxicity & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercapnia#Tolerance, I am taking up to 5% concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> as acceptable for the duration of the underwater walk.
3. Actual air composition calculation

   3.1. Initial air composition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_chemistry#Atmospheric_composition):

   - O<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 21%
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 0.04% (or 400 ppm)

   Thus, for 2 m<sup>3</sup> of air (= 2000 L),

   - O<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 420 L
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 0.8 L

   3.2. Final air composition (Based on acceptable limits above, final concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> = 5%). Thus:

   - O<sub>2</sub> (final) = 16%
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (final) = 5%

   Thus, for 2 m<sup>3</sup> of air (= 2000 L),

   - O<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 320 L
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (initial) = 100 L

   Thus, we have time until the 2 people (Jack and Will) have exhaled 100 L of CO<sub>2</sub>.

   3.3. Time taken to exhale 100 L of CO<sub>2</sub> (by 1 person).

   Composition of exhaled air (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing#Composition):

   - O<sub>2</sub> (exhaled breath) = 17%
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (exhaled breath) = 4%

   Volume of exhaled air per breath (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing#Gas_exchange) = 350 mL.
   Thus:

   - O<sub>2</sub> (exhaled breath) = 17% of 350 mL = 59.5%
   - CO<sub>2</sub> (exhaled breath) = 4% of 350 mL = 14 mL

   Thus, Volume of exhaled CO<sub>2</sub> per breath = 14 mL
   Assuming 15 breaths per minute,
   => Volume of exhaled air per minute = 15 * 14 mL = 210 mL
   => CO<sub>2</sub> exhalation rate = 210 mL / minute

   Thus time taken to exhale 100 L of CO<sub>2</sub> (by 1 person) = (100 L) / (210 mL / minute)
   = (100 * 1000 mL) / (210 mL / minute) = 476 minutes.

   => time taken to exhale 100 L of CO<sub>2</sub> by 2 people = 476 / 2 minutes = 238 minutes ~ 4 hours.

Thus, Jack and Will will be able to last 4 hours breathing from that air under the row boat before the air concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> reaches 5% (and O<sub>2</sub> reaches 16%).

Comment: You've not taken into account that the CO2 dissolves in the water, the surface area of the water, the rate of dissolution. Also... maybe additional O2 from the water? (I'd need to check that). That would need to be balanced-out against extra metabolic and muscular use of oxygen from the effort expended.. Just a thought.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. As long as the pO2 is different in the water and the air there will be a net diffusion between them. pO2 of the water will be roughly equivalent to atmospheric pO2 at the surface, where air and water are mixed.

Comment: Glad you took the time to answer your own question. It's a well-laid out answer. Good job! I agree with the previous comment about CO2 (though I'm less convinced the oxygen pressures will make a big enough difference to matter). Anyway, the reason for my comment is that I wanted to additionally point out that 15 breaths/min might be reasonable *while at rest*, but these two individuals would likely be breathing faster (i.e., producing more CO2 per minute) given their activity. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4818249/ suggests 40-60 breaths/min is more normal during exercise.